# Populating drop down with json object

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I have managed to populate my drop down menu with a json object, which worked fine. 
Currently I am trying to display an image which is in a hidden div based on an option selected from the drop down. As the drop down is populated by the json object how would I retrieve the image data.

**Html**

```
<form>
    <fieldset id="autoHeight">
        <legend>pod</legend>
        <h2>Cars</h2>
        <select name="drop_down" id="dropDownCars">
            <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select type</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="showBmw" class="hidden">
    <a href="http://cdn.iphoneincanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/white-bmw.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

**JSON File**

```
{
    Cars: [{
        "CarType": "BMW",
        "carID": "bmw123"
    }, {
        "CarType": "mercedes",
        "carID": "merc123"
    }, {
        "CarType": "volvo",
        "carID": "vol123r"
    }, {
        "CarType": "ford",
        "carID": "ford123"
    }]
}
```

This is how I populate the dropdown menu using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("../cars.json", function(obj) {
        $.each(obj.cars, function(key, value) {
            $("#dropDownCars").append("<option>" + value.carsName + "</option>");
        });
    });
});
```

Any working example in jfiddle, would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: A fiddle or posting your HTML would be helpful as well.

Comment: Add a value attribute to the option and a change-handler to the dropdown box which reads the current active ID and sets the src of the image accordingly.
For 30 bugs I'll do your work ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#dropDownDest').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'vol123r') {
        $('#imghide').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#imghide').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yhD9A/1/)**

Answer (score 17):

Try this piece of code....[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2PV7/)
it explains where to put the code to select image based on the selected drop down id

Html code

```
 <select id="dropDownDest">
</select>
```

jQuery document.ready code

```
 var a = {
            Cars: [{
                "CarType": "BMW",
                "carID": "bmw123"
            }, {
                "CarType": "mercedes",
                "carID": "merc123"
            }, {
                "CarType": "volvo",
                "carID": "vol123r"
            }, {
                "CarType": "ford",
                "carID": "ford123"
            }]
        };
        $.each(a.Cars, function (key, value) {
            $("#dropDownDest").append($('<option></option>').val(value.carID).html(value.CarType));
        });

        $('#dropDownDest').change(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            //Code to select image based on selected car id
        });
```

Comment: Just seen this comment, this also does the job. Thankyou @iblue

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5czG4/)**

Try this code..

```
var obj={
Cars: [
     {
      "CarType": "BMW",
      "carID": "bmw123"
      },
       {
      "CarType": "mercedes",
      "carID": "merc123"
       },
       {
      "CarType": "volvo",
      "carID": "vol123r"
        },
        {
      "CarType": "ford",
      "carID": "ford123"
        }
   ]
};

for(var i=0;i<obj.Cars.length;i++)
{
    var option=$('<option></option>').text(obj.Cars[i]['CarType']);
  $('select').append(option);

}
```