# Setting a default value in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem regarding how to set a default value in a `dropdown` list.
The object is not hard coded - I got this from a large `json` string.

```
Object {car: "car",  Consumer: " Consumer", truck: "truck", train: "train",  Business: " Business"}
```

Comment: Nothing is clear. Please add the complete code, and also which `option` should be selected by default.

Comment: your question wasn't clear enough, maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484762/populating-drop-down-with-json-object

Comment: lets say i need default car .

Comment: After populating, jquery: `$("#selectID").val("car")` plain JS: `document.getElementById("selectID").value="car"`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/0w9gezfn/2/

```
 var obj = {car: "car", Consumer: " Consumer", truck: "truck", train: "train", Business: " Business"};

 var option_val = "";
    jQuery.each(obj , function(index, value){
       option_val += "<option value = '"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>"
     });

  $("#kamote").append(option_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using my own js function for filling selects.
You need to pass the data array .. so your object to Array.

```
function FillSelect (dataArr, strFieldName, strValueProperty, strDisplayProperty, strSelectedvalue) {
    var xField = document.getElementById(strFieldName);
    if (xField != null) {
        while (xField.options.length > 0) {
            xField.remove(0);
        }
        if (dataArr != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
                var xRec = dataArr[i];
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.value = xRec[strValueProperty];
                opt.innerHTML = xRec[strDisplayProperty];
                xField.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
        xField.value = strSelectedvalue;
    }    
}
```