# Unable to bind dropdown in MVC4 Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am binding dropdown using jquery MVC4. In controller I am getting all the required values but when i put alert in jquery success call,it displays empty. It shows [object,object]. This is what i tried so far.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("getrejectReason", "DocumentVerification")",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function () {
        alert(" An error occurred.");
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        $.each(result, function (index, item) {
            options.append($("<option/>").val(item.value).text(item.text));
        });
    }
});

<select id="options"></select>
```

This is server side code.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getrejectReason()
{
    DB_KYC3Entities db = new DB_KYC3Entities();
    var result = new SelectList(db.dbo_tm_rejectcomment, "Id", "RejectComment");
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Do no use `alert()` to debug code. Your method is sending back a serialized `SelectList` so your `$.each()` code needs to be `$('#options').append($("<option/>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text));`.

Comment: It should be like `options.append($("<option>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text));` and you have to declare option first on success `var options= $("#options");`

Comment: But there are multiple other issues - remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (your not even sending anything let alone stringifying it. `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is pointless since your making a POST. You do not send back a `SelectList` - send back an anonymous object of just what you need.

Comment: Thank you, i changed everything as you said. I removed content type. I am getting error in the below line saying missing bracket but i have all brackets.     options.append($("<option>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text)‌​); missing ) after argument list

Comment: I changed as below   return Json(result); Is this coorect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating drop down with json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484762/populating-drop-down-with-json-object)

Comment: I fixed that error but my problem is I am receiving null values

Comment: Your controller should be `var result =db.dbo_tm_rejectcomment.Select(x => new { Value =  x.Id, Text = x.RejectComment }); return Json(result);`

Comment: And why are you populating the `<select>` using ajax - you should have sent the `SelectList` to the view when you initially rendered it.

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks. Please add answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller method is passing back a serialized `SelectList` which contains properties `Value` and `Text` (uppercase), so to add the options you need to refer to the same properties (uppercase).

```
options.append($("<option/>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
```

However there are a few other issues with your code.

1. Your not sending any data in the request, so `contentType:
   "application/json; charset=utf-8",` is unnecessary
2. Your method is marked `[HttpPost]`, so using
   `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is unnecessary
3. You should only send back data that the view uses (there is no point
   sending back the additional properties of `SelectListItem` to the
   client, so the code in the method should generate a collection of
   anonymous objects

   ```
   var model = db.dbo_tm_rejectcomment
       .Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text = x.RejectComment });
   return Json(model);
   ```

But your ajax call is unnecessary and your effectively telling the client - *here is the view, but I forgot to send all the data, so wait a bit longer and make another request to get it*. You should be generating you view using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRejectReason, Model.RejectReasonList)
```

where `RejectReasonList` is a property in your view model that is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

As a side note, do not use `alert()` for debugging. Add `debugger;` in your script (or set a breakpoint) so that you can step through the script and inspect the variables. If you do want to print the output, use `console.log()` which would have allowed you to expand the output and see the actual objects in the array.